# IncompatibleClassChangeError on Android using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I wan't to compile my project on Android and I got this following error :

```
Java.Lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: 'No static method getFont(Landroid/content/Context;ILandroid/util/TypedValue;ILandroid/widget/TextView;)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat' appears in /data/app/Digibois.LogiStock--0DmxMZxf8_3l0NMh1wijQ==/base.apk)'
```

There is my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.3.4.0" package="Digibois.LogiStock" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="LogiStock" android:icon="@drawable/icon"></application>
</manifest>
```

Im using an emulator with Android 6.0 API 23. I also tried with Android 8.1 API 27.

I tried to search a lot of solution but I found anything about it. 
Thank's for your help !

Comment: Hi, whether it's a new created Xamarin.Android project ? Having a check with [Setting up the Android SDK for Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows) to be sure the environment is no problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a check with whether installing [Xamarin.Android.Support.v4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4/28.0.0.3?_src=template) NugetPackage :

[image]

In addition , to be sure the environment is no problem with [Setting up the Android SDK for Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows).